# Play Template Engine: how to pass an implicit parameter

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to pass an implicit parameter to a Play template... here below is my code:

`test.scala.html:`

```
@(implicit request: RequestHeader)

@()(implicit p = Some(controllers.routes.MyController.myActionMethod().absoluteURL))
@main("My Title") {

    // some HTML here...
}
```

`main.scala.html:`

```
@(title: String)(implicit request: RequestHeader, p: Option[String])

<html>
    ...
</html>
```

`p` is never assigned... and I always get error message `could not find implicit value for parameter p`. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've just figured out how to make it work:

```
@(implicit request: RequestHeader)

@defining(Some(controllers.routes.MyController.myActionMethod().absoluteURL)) { implicit p =>

    // now main is able to access p
    @main("My Title") {
    ...
}}
```